# C# HttpWebRequest doesn't get set

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to set the Accept header to allow the server to return me the data in Json format.

```
HttpWebRequest lvRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lvURL);
lvRequest.Method = "GET";
lvRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

The server does't receive the accept header.

What do I miss?
Do you now a test server I can use to see the headers I send?

Comment: Are you also setting the `Headers` property of `HttpWebRequest`? If you set that property, whatever value you set previously in the `Accept` property is erased.

Comment: @Discoverer98 No I don't use Headers